# Having and error with my shaders and don't know how to fix

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am trying to set my shaders in my code and is not running

I am at my Mac, my partner can run it perfectly but I can't, I have OpenGl 3.3

This is part of my code where the error happens, I have tried changing the version of the shaders, running it in different environments, used PyCharm, the idle, Jupyter notebook...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Initialize glfw
    if not glfw.init():
        sys.exit()

    width = 800
    height = 600

    window = glfw.create_window(width, height, "Window name", None, None)

    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        sys.exit()

    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    # Connecting the callback function 'on_key' to handle keyboard events
    glfw.set_key_callback(window, on_key)


    # Defining shaders for our pipeline
    vertex_shader = """
    #version 330
    in vec3 position;
    in vec3 color;

    out vec3 fragColor;

    void main()
    {
        fragColor = color;
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    }
    """

    fragment_shader = """
    #version 330

    in vec3 fragColor;
    out vec4 outColor;

    void main()
    {
        outColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0f);
    }
    """

    vertex_shader2 = """
    #version 330
    in vec3 position;
    in vec3 color;

    out vec3 fragColor;

    void main()
    {
        fragColor = color;
        gl_Position = vec4(2 * position, 1.0f);
    }
    """

    fragment_shader2 = """
    #version 330

    in vec3 fragColor;
    out vec4 outColor;

    void main()
    {
        float meanColor = (fragColor.r + fragColor.g + fragColor.b) / 3;
        outColor = vec4(meanColor, meanColor, meanColor,  1.0f);
    }
    """

# Assembling the shader program (pipeline) with both shaders
shaderProgram = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(
    OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
    OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(fragment_shader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

shaderProgram2 = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(
    OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader2, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
    OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(fragment_shader2, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
```

It should draw a triangle, but show the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/gustavo/PycharmProjects/untitled1/oli.py", line 186, in <module>
   OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),  
 File "/Users/gustavo/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.py", line 226, in compileShader
   shaderType,  
RuntimeError: ('Shader compile failure (0): b'ERROR: 0:2: '' :  version '130' is not supported\n ERROR: 0:11: 'f' : syntax error: syntax error\n '', [b'
   #version 130
   in vec3 position;
   in vec3 color;

   out vec3 fragColor;

   void main()
   {
       fragColor = color;
       gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
   }
   '], GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
```

Comment: Is this the code you are for sure running? It is complaining about version `130` in the error but your code uses `330`. The error also shows code using `130` not `330`.

Comment: I tried both, the same error raises :(

Comment: Since most experienced GL users picked up on the '130' vs '330', I think it was lazy to close the question - as the answer below suggests, this is simply seems to be a genuine confusion about the boundary between the GL and system-specific context creation. Very lazy attitude to a new user, who should be cut a bit of slack.

Answer (score 3):

MacOS uses Legacy Profile as default for all created OpenGL context. Therefor by default only OpenGL up to 2.1 and GLSL up to 1.20 is supported.

To use OpenGL 3.2+ you need to switch to the Core Profile. The naming there is a little bit confusing because it stats only 3.2Core profile, but actually this 3.2 or later (every OpenGL profile that is supported by the system/driver that is backwards compatible to 3.2)

For glut (depends on the version of glut if it works) the command on MacOS is:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

Sorry I am not aware of python version but it should be similar functions.